# moving button bar

Tags: android, android-layout, buttonbar

I have an activity that allows me to enter content. It consists of edit text and button bar. Whenever I what to input something to the edit text, a keyboard pops up and the button bar is on top if it so I can't see what I'm typing if the content is long(it goes behind the button bar). How can i fix it ?
[image]

[image]

my code is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/toplayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/notetop"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etTitleJoke"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title_text1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="@string/no_title"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" >

    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>

<view
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/etContentJoke"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toplayout"
    class="ie.myjokes.LineEditText"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:capitalize="sentences"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="22sp" >

    <requestFocus />
</view>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClickSave"
        android:text="@string/btn_save"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClickCancel"
        android:text="@string/btn_cancel"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the main layout(that has the view layout inside)?

Comment: it seems its without layout

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I added this line into my activity and its gone now. Thank you

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```